# How to avoid column gap spaces - margin and padding set to 0 doesn't work

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I try to open simple test html in firefox, everything is fine, but when opening it in Chrome or on mobile device I get this white gaps between columns.
Does anyone understand why?

If you have any idea how to solve this, I would really appreciate it. The thing is, it works great with firefox, however Chrome and mobile devices do not recognize this as an object with out any gaps.

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
  border:1px solid;
">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
">
            <button id="11" class="button" type="button" style="  background-color:green;
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
  border:none;
  display:flexbox;
  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10" style="  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
">
            <button id="12" class="button" type="button" style="  background-color:green;
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
  border:none;
  display:flexbox;
  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
">
            <button id="13" class="button" type="button" style="  background-color:green;
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
  border:none;
  display:flexbox;
  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
">
            <button id="14" class="button" type="button" style="  background-color:green;
  height:160px;
  width:100%;
  border:none;
  display:flexbox;
  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10" style="  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
">
            <button id="15" class="button" type="button" style="  background-color:greeen;
  height:160px;
  width:100%;
  border:none;
  display:flexbox;
  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
">
            <button id="16" class="button" type="button" style="  background-color:green;
  height:160px;
  width:100%;
  border:none;
  display:flexbox;
  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
">
            <button id="17" class="button" type="button" style="  background-color:green;
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
  border:none;
  display:flexbox;
  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10" style="  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
">
            <button id="18" class="button" type="button" style="  background-color:green;
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
  border:none;
  display:flexbox;
  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
">
            <button id="19" class="button" type="button" style="  background-color:green;
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
  border:none;
  display:flexbox;
  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buttons are natively inline elements.  Therefore they have spaces to the right and below just like words in a sentence do.

To easily fix this you just need to style the buttons with `display: block;`

By the way, there's no such thing as `display: flexbox;`  I think you were thinking `flex` but that wouldn't work anyway because `display: flex;` would be for a container that contains flex content made up of all its children.

Comment: flexbox was the unoffical syntax used in 2011. display: flex is what is used now

Comment: nor should you be. I came across it in this guide as a brief mention. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you Haltersweb, it's true, block was the solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

## Close but your height and display type were off

For you buttons their height were `5px` short each, thus creating that grab you saw. They also needed to be displayed as type `block` considering they way you were using them.

So for example, boostrap was automatically setting the height of the containers to `45px`, and their height by default was `40px`. This created a gap the gap of white space you saw prior.

```
button {
 height: 45px;
 display: block;
}
```

## [Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/20sdr6d3/)

Comment: Thank you Dominic, yes this is true.